# SQL Server 2008 Requirements

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I've read a few questions at stackoverflow and some msdn articles too about SQL Server 2008 system requirements but there's something that i'vent understand yet.

I've installed the SQL Server 2008 Express. I'm not using the Management Studio, just running the service of SQL Server and manage the databases with others softwares.

My question is about the standard 2008 and R2 2008. Is there a big difference in performance between those two? (just to running the sql server service, not using the tools).

I'm asking this because i just have 2GB in this laptop, and the PC is running very well with the Express but now i'm thinking about upgrade it to R2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GuilHerme,

I am NOT sure there are some significant performance benefits between the two. The one nice thing about SQL Server 2008 R2 is you can have 10 GB for the database now instead of 4 GB in SQL Server 2008.

Note that the SQL Engine is same across the all editions but SQL Express comes with limitations on the cpu and memory. You can use only 1 core [it uses multi-cores but only one at a time] and can use only 1 GB for data cache. In total you may use more than 1.3 to 1.5 GB of memory but note that data pages will use only 1 GB.

With those limitations, I don't think you will get good performance benefits between those 2 versions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try to install the R2 and i'll see how my laptop handles with it. Perhaps it run as well it's running the Express ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the MSDN information on performance improvements in 2008 R2:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645580.aspx

There are a number of other improvements made to the database engine as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510411.aspx

Comment: But those improvements don't cost more use of memory and cpu from the SQL Server Service?

Comment: SQL Server likes to grab as much memory as it can.  You can set the maximum amount of memory that it uses which should help your performance.  Of course getting more RAM would help.  :)  Here is info about setting max memory:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx